# File path with "$(TopDir)\**\packages.config"

Tags: msbuild

This sounds really basic but couldn't find any info on internet about it.I am working with msbuild and inside a .proj file I found the following line

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageFiles Include="$(TopDir)\**\packages.config" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I know that ".\" means current directory and "..\" previous one, but what about "**\"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with paths in CMD or DOS. This is how MSBuild's wildcards work. You can read about them [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms171453.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_3). Basically, `**` matches a partial *path*, so in your case the items include all `packages.config` from any subfolders of `$(TopDir)`. (And `$(TopDir)` would be specified in some `<PropertyGroup>` elsewhere.)

Answer (score 1):

That 'double star' (i.e. **) in msbuild is used with items. 
It means get all sub-directories. In your example code, it can be read as: Under the top directory, get all packages.config files in all sub-directories.

The latest docs are at Microsoft here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-select-the-files-to-build